# How is easier to set an anchor with a random href?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, in my project I have an index and a directory with a bunch of numbered pages (pages/001.html, pages/002.hmtl, pages/003.html...), and I want to set an `<a>` that changes his href to any of this pages every time the index is reloaded/the anchor is clicked.

I could make an array writing every url and use .random() to generate the links, but the thing is, I have a LOT of numbered pages (like 30 for the moment), and I pretend to create more eventually, so I wonder if there's an easier, faster way to do it.

The code should be something like:

```
$('random_button').on('click', function(){

  $('random_button').attr("href", Any page inside the directory pages/ chosen randomly)

})
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Can have server side script read the directory and create the array

Comment: are all your pages named as numbers: 001, 002, 003, ...,101, 102... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have similar patterns in your html file names, like 001.html, 002.html, then you could do something like this

```js
var openLink = document.getElementById('open');
var randomLink = document.getElementById('random');
/*
assuming there are 40 pages, and page name have patterns like 001.html, 002.html
*/
var pageArray = range(40).map(function(page){
 if(page < 10) return '00' + page + '.html';
 return '0' + page +'.html';
});



/* 
this function will return a array of n elements 
*/
function range(n){
  return Array.from({length: n}, function(value, key){ return key;})
}

function getRandomPage(pageArray){
 return pageArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*pageArray.length)]
}
openLink.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
   console.log(getRandomPage(pageArray));
 randomLink.href = getRandomPage(pageArray); 
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="open">Open Random</a>
<a href="#" id="random">Random Link</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

If you have different types of file name then this won't work, and php solution provided by @Jozef Cipa would be better

Comment: yes, all pages are numbered like that, thinking that would be useful in the future. I'm trying your way, thanks :D

Comment: Yes, pretty sweet, it worked perfectly! and I assume the 40 in your example could be replaced by something like `obj.length` in case I add new pages. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, glad it worked, you could replace 40 with any valid integer.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy. Check your `selector`. You are either missing a `.` or `#`.

```js
$(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
    var el = $("ul li a").eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $("ul li a").length));
    $("#randomLink").attr("href", el.attr("href")).html(el.html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<h3>List of Links to Choose From</h3>
<ul>
  <li><a href="//example.com/link1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="//example.com/link2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="//example.com/link3">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="//example.com/link4">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="//example.com/link5">Link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="//example.com/link6">Link 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="//example.com/link7">Link 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="//example.com/link8">Link 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="//example.com/link9">Link 9</a></li>
  <li><a href="//example.com/link10">Link 10</a></li>
  <li><a href="//example.com/link11">Link 11</a></li>
  <li><a href="//example.com/link12">Link 12</a></li>
  <li><a href="//example.com/link13">Link 13</a></li>
  <li><a href="//example.com/link14">Link 14</a></li>
  <li><a href="//example.com/link15">Link 15</a></li>
</ul>
<h3>The random link!</h3>
<button type="button">Generate Random Link</button><br />
<a href="" id="randomLink"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this way I have to write every link right? that was my main concern, to do it dinamically in case I have to insert more pages in the future

Comment: @batxe Get it from the PHP. This technically answers your question of taking a random link from the page.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you could make something like

```
$files = glob('your_dir/*.html');
//now you have array of your html files
```

Now just send this in to your Javascript.

Comment: I should've said that I have absolutely no clue about PHP, but if it seems that easy, maybe it's worth looking at, thanks :)

Comment: @batxe Did you check mine?